# Why doesn't c++ allow (auto) casting?

Tags: c++, casting

When converting from for example a void* to a PMY_OBJECT, one would have to do something like this:

```
void MyFunction(void* v) {

    PMY_OBJECT p = (PMY_OBJECT) v;

}
```

In C, you don't have to cast it at all, but in c++ the closest thing would be:

```
PMY_OBJECT p = (decltype(p)) v;
```

Why not simply:

```
PMY_OBJECT p = (auto) v;
```

?

Comment: `auto p = (PMY_OBJECT) v;`?

Comment: When we write in C, we think in C. When we write in C++, we think in C++. :) Don't mix.

Comment: can you reveal why you have `void*` in code?

Comment: You can write a function `auto_cast` such that `PMY_OBJECT = auto_cast(v)` does what you want.

Comment: @MarekR Most probably the function interface has to conform to e.g. some C callback fptr API.

Comment: @Jarod42 you do realize p may be a class member?

Comment: @Marc Glisse please post an answer i beg you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write `auto_cast` yourself:

```
#include <utility>

template <typename From>
class auto_cast {
public:
    explicit constexpr auto_cast(From const& t) noexcept
        : val { t }
    {
    }

    template <typename To>
    constexpr operator To() const noexcept(noexcept(static_cast<To>(std::declval<From>())))
    {
        return static_cast<To>(val);
    }

private:
    From const& val;
};

void foo(void* p)
{
    int* ip = auto_cast(p);
    char* cp = auto_cast(p);
    double* dp = auto_cast(p);
}
```

Comment: @super how does my `auto_cast` "function" not do exactly what you wanted? I'd appreciate any feedback.

Comment: "The solution is: auto p = static_cast<Long_name_I_dont_want_to_repeat>(v);" - clearly not in the regard I proposed. Besides, does auto_cast actually guarantee compile-time casting?

Comment: @super thank you for the feedback. I removed the irrelevant part and now the function is constexpr. Compilers are good at elision of the function call in this particular case. See the asm in a couple of cases if you're not sure.

Answer (score 6):

This is all speaking in hypotheticals, mind you, because the C++ is designed by a commitee that has to consider a lot of special cases and nitpicks.

That being said, C++ explicitly discourages using the `(type)val` syntax; `static_cast`, `dynamic_cast` and other explicit casts are preferred, because that makes it that much easier to spot bugs stemming from improper casts.

In fact, as the other answer/comment mentions, in the specific case in your question (initializing a variable), you can use `auto` for that variable type and force the type of the initializer with e.g. `static_cast`, like so:

```
auto p = static_cast<PMY_OBJECT>(v);
```

This is actually quite common; I've seen it used and used it at least a good couple times. However, pay attention to not *over* use it in cases where it's not necessary, because you might end up negating a lot of benefits that `auto` brings in the first place.

By allowing `(auto)` (which is effectively forced coercion) you're introducing back all the problems associated with the C-style casts, for very little gained convenience.